# How to have my bash script executed every time the touch screen receives input?

Tags: scripts, touchscreen

I am looking for a way to trigger a little bash script I wrote to run every time the touchscreen receives input. I am assuming there is some sort of event handler somewhere that deals with touchscreen input I could tamper with to do this, but as I am not a very experienced linux user I have no clue where to start. Currently running Xubuntu 15.04, please let me know if you need more info than that (and how I can get it for you).

I'm having this 'problem' that people keep touching my screen in meetings, and, not expecting it to be a touch screen, mess things up. Now, rather than disable the touchscreen feature somehow, I though it would be very humorous to have my laptop protest, using a voice synthesiser, saying things like 'ouch' and 'stop poking me'. So I wrote a little script that cycles through an array of them and saves which one it last said in a text file, which I would like to trigger with every touch... :). I can't wait to see my colleagues faces.

Edit:

So with a friends suggestion I am now most of the way there:

I have now found a way to check for touch using 'evtest /dev/input/event7'

It will give the possible event codes for the device first, and will then listen in terminal until a touch occurs, at which time it displays logs like this:

```
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value 7
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 3057
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 1498
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 60 (ABS_MT_TOOL_X), value 3057
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 61 (ABS_MT_TOOL_Y), value 1498
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 49 (ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR), value 2
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 3057
Event: time 1470832989.871275, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 1498
Event: time 1470832989.871275, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

So I now have a script that runs until it finds a touch;

```
#!/bin/bash

how_many_touches=10

touch_detected=0
while [ "$touch_detected" -lt "$how_many_touches" ]; do
timeout 0.1s evtest /dev/input/event7 > touchscreen_log.txt

grep "type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)" touchscreen_log.txt &>/dev/null
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then &>/dev/null
        echo 'No touch detected' &>/dev/null
    else touch_detected=$[$touch_detected+1] &>/dev/null
        bash quit_poking_me.sh &>/dev/null
        sleep 1
    fi
    echo $touch_detected &>/dev/null
done
```

Which is very nice. Now I have several small questions left:

- I would also welcome any input on how to get around the fact that evtest needs root priviliges. It would be nice to be able to run this without root.
- Does anyone have a better option to mute ALL output within script? This mutes most, but still outputs errors from GSSpeechServer in terminal.

Many thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @jacobvlijm here is one for you :)

Comment: @Narameh For future reference, please avoid dropping F bombs in questions.

Comment: What is the state of the screen you want this to happen? I assume you don't want it on every time you touch it :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm apologies for getting back on this so late. Actually, I do want this to happen *every time* someone touches the screen. I will only run it during meetings. My friend mentioned I have to start by creating a running daemon and then figure out how to read the state of the screen every x time. Any help with where to start figuring this out would be very welcome!

Comment: @JacobVlijm I seem to have found an easier way to do this, please see edits above :).